# Where are we getting the value of this parameter?

Tags: c++, function, opencv, parameter-passing

In a program in the `Learning OpenCV` book:

```
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
{
cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,pos);
}
```

And, in another location:

```
if(frames!=0)
{
cvCreateTrackbar("Position","Example3",&g_slider_position,frames,onTrackbarSlide);
}
```

Where are we retrieving the value of `pos` in the `onTrackSlide(int pos)` function  from? What value will be passed to it from `cvCreateTrackbar()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check the docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html#createtrackbar) and you'll see the function signature is:

```
cvCreateTrackbar(const char* trackbarName, const char* windowName, int* value, int count, CvTrackbarCallback onChange)
```

Notice that the last parameter has the type `CvTrackbarCallback`. Obviously, this is not a built-in type, but a type defined by OpenCV. So we go back to the documentation to find more about it and interestingly enough, this information shows up:

> The function cvCreateTrackbar() creates a trackbar (a.k.a. slider or range control) with the specified name and range, assigns a variable to be syncronized with trackbar position and specifies a **callback function** to be called on trackbar position change.

And right below this paragraph, you can see how a `CvTrackbarCallback` should be declared:

```
CV_EXTERN_C_FUNCPTR( void (*CvTrackbarCallback)(int pos) );
```

To summarize, in order to call `cvCreateTrackbar()` you need to declared a function with the signature `void some_fun(int pos)`, to be able to be notified by OpenCV when the slider of the trackbar is updated. The argument `int pos` informs the new position of the slider.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know OpenCV - but it looks like `onTrackbarSlide` is some sort of event handler, so it is passed a value of pos from the trackbar UI that you are creating.

There is no value of pos directly passed from `cvCreateTrackbar()` - that looks like it creates your trackbar UI, and then if interacted with by the user will call `onTrackBarSlide`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you can see in `cvCreateTrackbar`, `onTrackbarSlide` is passed as an argument, but where is the call to `onTrackbarSlide(int pos)` occuring?

Comment: @Med-SWEng This call is made by one of the OpenCV's internal functions to let you know when the slider of the trackbar is updated.